# FT232 USB serial connection error

Tags: usb-drive, serial-port, dmesg

I have a serial uart device - FT232. I cant get it to communicate with my python program.

When connecting the device I'm getting an error message on dmesg:

**Unable to read latency timer: -32**

And cant read the timer data currectly.

The `dmesg` Output:

```
[21094.951739] ftdi_sio 1-2:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[21094.951843] usb 1-2: Detected FT232RL
[21094.951949] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: Unable to read latency timer: -32
[21094.952720] usb 1-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

The `lsusb` gets me:
Bus 001 Device 087: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 Serial (UART) IC

Comment: `dmesg` says that the device is attached to `/dev/ttyUSB0`. So what is the problem? Does `/dev/ttyUSB0` exist? How do you want to communicate from your python program?

Comment: Well i want to read the timer, which i cannot access due to this error. I HAVEN'T tried anything else yet.